# bash work with escape space and special characters mac os x

Tags: bash, macos

I have come across an issue that is usually easily worked around but for some reason I cant get around it here.
In mac os x, I would like to set the network config with the DNS servers, and set the search domains.
Using the command networksetup -listallnetworkservices
shows:
Display Ethernet
Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 2
Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 3
Display FireWire
Wi-Fi
Bluetooth PAN

This works:
networksetup -getdnsservers "Display Ethernet"
There aren't any DNS Servers set on Display Ethernet.

But when trying to modify the 'Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 2' port, I cannot for some reason escape the spaces and comma properly.  See these examples:

networksetup -getdnsservers Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port2
Thunderbolt is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

networksetup -getdnsservers 'Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port2'
Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port2 is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot1, Port2"
Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot1, Port2 is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt\ Ethernet\ Slot\ 1,\ Port2"
Thunderbolt\ Ethernet\ Slot\ 1,\ Port2 is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

Not sure what I am doing wrong, and thought this was the way to escape these characters, but not sure what I am missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried just `networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1"`?

Comment: Sorry, that one didn't work either: networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1"
Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1 is not a recognized network service.
** Error: The parameters were not valid.

Comment: this works:     networksetup -getdnsservers "Display Firewire"
There aren't any DNS Servers set on Display Firewire.

Answer (score 0):

Using copy and paste of:
networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 2"

seems to work:
networksetup -getdnsservers "Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 3"
There aren't any DNS Servers set on Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Port 3.

For some reason hand typing it wouldn't work, probably from bad typing.

Comment: It's also possible there's a weird character in the actual service name, like a nonbreaking space (which look just like regular spaces). Try `networksetup -listallnetworkservices | LC_ALL=C cat -vt`, and see if it shows anything strange.